# Test Coverage for Apex Class! On executing test class i am getting this error 'System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject'

Tags: apex, code-coverage, lightning-community, health-cloud, customer-community-plus

```
public without sharing class UserDetails {
         
    @AuraEnabled 
    public static Account Details()
    {
   
     String UserId=UserInfo.getUserId();
     String contactId=utility.getUserContactId(UserId);  
       
     Account acc = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE PersonContactId =: contactId];
        
     return acc;
        
       
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read about [ask], and take the [tour]. Please don't state that your question is "urgent", as that is unhelpful. Also, what resources have you looked at so far? Where are you stuck? How can we help you?

Comment: Hello, @sfdcfox i am a newbie, i am running this test method(getLoggedInUserId) with test data factory method getAccount but on executing the test method, test fails as well as i get a error i.e ''System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My issue is resolved now by the code below.This code is very helpful when person account is enable in your org.

```
@isTest    
static void testM()
    {
Account a = new Account();
       a.firstName = 'Nike';
       a.LastName = 'James';
       a.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get('Your recod type name').getRecordTypeId();
       a.PersonEmail='nike@g.com';
       insert a;
     
        Account acc= [SELECT id,Name From Account Where id =: a.Id ];
        
        Profile profileID = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile WHERE Name= 'your profile name'];
        List<Contact> lstContact = [SELECT Id FROM contact WHERE  accountId   =:  acc.Id];
        Contact con = lstContact[0];
        
        User u = new User();
        u.LastName = 'James';
        u.FirstName = 'Nike';
        u.Email = 'nike@g.com';
        u.Alias = 'James'+'00';
        u.Username = 'nike@g.com';
        u.CommunityNickname ='N' + ' '+ 'James';
        u.ContactId = con.Id;
        u.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
        u.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles';
        u.IsActive = true;
        u.ProfileID = profileID.id;
        u.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
        u.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';    
                 
        insert u;
        
        User userForTesting = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id =: u.Id LIMIT 1];
        
          system.runAs(userForTesting)
        {
            test.startTest();

             String contactId=utility.getUserContactId(userForTesting.Id);  
             Account acnt = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE PersonContactId =: contactId];
             UserDetails.Details();
            
            test.stopTest();

        }
}
```

Comment: If one of the answers posted gave you a solution, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark. This gives you and the answerer both a bit of rep. You do not need to post revised versions of your code.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the code that's provided and without a specific line number or method call that the error is coming from, I don't think that an Account *or* Contact is ever inserted within the unit test. Therefore there may not be a Contact to return from `utility.getUserContactId(UserId)`. There may also not be any Accounts to return from either `Community_TestDataFactory.getAccount` nor `Community_UserDetails.membershipDetails`.

Insert a Contact and Account within your unit test block so that there is data to work with within the unit test.

I would also ensure your query cannot return *more than one* Account record based on the `PersonContactId` field (I am not sure if that's a unique field or not).

Comment: Put another way... Unit tests don't have access to most data in your org. In a unit test, you are responsible for creating the data required to run your test (which in this case would be an `Account` and a `Contact` at the very least).

Answer (score 2):

Just a bit of a hint.
Whenever you try to write test methods to test your code, always follow the rule of AAA.
i.e.

Arrange,
Act,
Assert

Arrange => create, insert and update your records upto the state in which your code will run.

Act => update your record in a way expecting the test will cover your code which you have implemented.

Assert => check for error messages that will fail the test if your code is not working properly.